# Python - ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to find the difference between maximum and minimum values from my csv file but I got the above mentioned error.

My code:

```
 file1  = open ('fileA.csv', 'rb')
 reader1 = csv.reader(file1)

 outfile = open ('fileB.csv', 'wb')
 writer = csv.writer(outfile)

 next(reader1, None)  # skip the headers
 for col in reader1:
     Max1 = max (col[3:6],key = float)
     Min1 = min (col[3:6], key = float)
     Data1 = str(float(Max1) - float (Min1))
     print Data1
     col.append (Data1)
     writer.writerow (col[9])
     Max2 =  max (col[6:9], key = float)
     Min2 = min(col[6:9], key = float)
     Data2 = str(float(Max2) - float(Min2))
     col.append (Data2)
     writer.writerow (col[10])



    file1.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Percentage_methylation_variation.py", line 13, in <module>
    Max1 = max (col[3:6],key = float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

FileA contains float numbers in each column. Any advice about this issue and other criticisms of my code would be of great help.

Many thanks.

Comment: Well when you create `outfile` you don't close your `fileB` string, fix that and see what happens.

Comment: Which is obvious from the syntax highlighting, fyi

Comment: How can we possibly know what is going on without the contents of the input file.

Comment: Although yes, it appears we're missing `'` - that'd be a `SyntaxError`... I suspect there's a blank value in one of the slices  (`col[3:6]`) and it's the `key=float` that's raising the error

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add that I ended fileB with a .csv. I missed that out in this post. Other details are as stated.

Comment: To help others help you: correct your code so it's free of syntax errors and it runs producing the error you're getting, then [edit] your post to put that code in, and post the *full* error that you get below it...

Comment: Also, I used (key = float) as the Max and Min function would not identify the right number in my csv file otherwise.

Comment: @user3302763 what does `col[3:6]` contain at that point? It's likely you have a blank value in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what values could be causing your error (it's likely you have a blank one) - doing something like this:

```
for col in reader1:
    try:
        Max1 = max(col[3:6], key=float)
    except ValueError:
        print '***OOOPS***', col[3:6]
        break
```

Then, you need to work out what you're meant to do with the invalid values...